# jQuery make an event available only when a div is visible and disable it while the div is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown(`.dropdown`) div that opens when I click on `.open`:

Html:

```
<div class="open">Open</div>
<div class="dropdown">Dropdown</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".open").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown").show();
});
```

Once the dropdown is open I'm using this jQuery script to close it when i click is made outside `.dropdown` div:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.dropdown').hide();
    console.log('click');
});

$('.open, .dropdown').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The problem is that the click event for `document` is executed even if the div is not visible. Now, I could check to see if the div is visible before executing the `.hide()` method but is there a solution to activate the event on the document when the div is visible and deactivate it when the div is hidden?

Comment: *"I could check to see if the div is visible before executing trying to hide that div"* - That seems like a reasonable approach.  Don't try to get creative with activating/deactivating *events*, always handle the event but just handle them with the logic you intend.  Note also that calling `.hide()` on an already hidden element does no harm.

Comment: Ok so then i could leave it as it is or i could check if the `.dropdown` div is visible inside the event listener but besides that i don't need to reinvent coding?

Comment: That'd be my approach.  I've only suggested this as a comment because the question as asked may indeed have an answer, conditionally responding to events in general.  But my suggestion is simply that I see no harm in doing what you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to bind a click event to the document anyways to hide the dropdown. So, what about doing something like:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(e){
     if ($(e.target).hasClass("open")) $(".dropdown").show();
     else $(".dropdown").hide();
    });
   });
```

It's more concise and you don't have to worry about event propagation.